# Suppress "Using tag with different case" message

Tags: tags

With `ignorecase`  set, I am able to jump to a tag `Foo` by typing `:ltag foo`. However, doing so causes the message

```
Using tag with different case!
```

to appear at the bottom of the screen, along with a ~0.5s delay during which vim does not update. The same message and delay appear when jumping to another tag (which does not match in case) with `:tnext` or `:tprevious`. This occurs even with `tagcase` set to `ignore`.

How can I prevent this from occurring? I can do so by preceding the command with `silent`, but this also suppresses the "tag x of y" message, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 4):

According to my reading of the code you've found the only way to avoid that stuff: use of `silent`.

This appends the warning...nothing can prevent it except for disabling `ignorecase` et al...

```
if (ic)
    STRCAT(IObuff, _("  Using tag with different case!"));
```

Then a bit later the warning is printed and a nice one second freeze is initiated...

```
if (ic && !msg_scrolled && msg_silent == 0)
{
    out_flush();
    ui_delay(1000L, TRUE);
}
```

As you can see, the only (partial cuz you lose the rest of the message) recourse is `silent`.

Why so strict? I'm guessing but it may be because doing case-insensitive matching "disables binary searching" of tags and apparently relies then on a secondary, slower search method. That's according to help: scroll down about 30 lines below `:h tag-priority` to see what I'm talking about.

Oh yeah, I should mention the location of the above code in case someone's interested. It's in *tag.c*, function `do_tag()`...which rings in at an eye popping nearly 1000 lines...imagine a function/method of that length in, say, Python or Java. ;) Anyways, just search for the warning in that file ("Using tag with different case!").

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out there's at least one way to avoid the message:

```
:ltag /\cfoo
```

will match a tag called `Foo` without producing error output. (Somehow `:ltag /foo` with `ignorecase` set, which should theoretically behave the same way, still produces the warning and delay on a tag `Foo`.)

To make this more convenient to type, I've added the mapping

```
nnoremap <Leader>t :ltag /\c
```

to my `.vimrc`. The one disadvantage here is that if you want to match a tag name exactly (say you also have a tag `barfoobaz`, which you don't want to match), you have to either type out `^foo$` or delete the `/\c` and type `Foo` (with correct capitalization, to avoid the delay).

Comment: There may be a subtle difference. If your tag files are "case-fold sorted" then matches can be found with the binary type of search when using `ignorecase`  and a simple search term. If you use a regex, though, Vim will do a linear search. (Per help, binary search is "a LOT faster"....presumably O(log n) vs O(n) or something like that)

Comment: Side note: some regexes, theoretically, should not prevent a binary search. For example, one that just uses `^` (start of line anchor). Whether Vim optimizes out such things I've not checked.